# Facebook Request Dialog not sending notifications

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am testing out the Facebook request dialog.  The dialog launches fine, but when I test it by sending a request to myself, from a friends account, I get a notification but when I open my notifications there is nothing there.  Is this a bug, is there something im not setting? Before I changed the message from the default one facebook uses in their tutorial, I got no notification at all.

Comment: I think it might be because I only have a website created, and no canvas app.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URLs are not correctly specified in you app settings.